# Block JavaScript operations until a promise is resolved

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch a file into a synchronous class. But I cannot solve a problem that appeared: I need to get a return value of a function and store it into a variable, although I do not know when the promise will be fulfilled. Can someone explain a way to get my body?

```
function fetchSource(name: string): string {
    let source: string | null;
    getFileContents(name).then((response) => source = response);
    if (!source) { // <-- here we do not know at runtime what the value of this varaible is
        throw new Error("Cannot fetch shader source file " + name + ".");
    }
    return source;
}
```